# how to open closed window in chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, user-experience

I have opened two windows in chrome browser,
in each window there are multiple pages .

the first window is the most important for me, the second window is for search tabs.

my problem is that I accidentally closed the first window(window with multiple pages) instead of closing the second window.

how to restore the closed window with all its pages ???
is it possible? is ther any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there is.

1. Click on the 3-bars below the 'X' Close button.
2. Click Recent Tabs (or "History and recent tabs" in newer versions).
3. Click on the first item where it states "N Tabs'; where N is the number of open tabs in the windows that was closed.

It will even work if you close the browser completely.

Added:
You could also open the History tab with CTRL-H and select each tab to open.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> also works when multiple tabs have been closed.

Comment: ⌘+Shift+T for mac users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to open a window you have closed with all the tabs unless it was closed unexpectedly and then there will be an option provided to you to restore the session, but if you closed it and allowed it to close then there is no solution, but you can look in your history to open up all the pages again?

Comment: not agree, there is an option in chrome>settings>"On Startup" I changed radio button to "Continue where you left off" so I can restore the window I closed with its tabs. however this option did not work for the above scenario for the last closed window, while other windows are still opened.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the desktop toolbar Chrome icon. It will bring up "Recently closed tabs." Click on one to re-open that one tab.  Then, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, and the rest of the closed tabs will reopen.